# Не переведена плашка на общих вопросах (community effort)

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, общие-сообщения

[image: плашка]

Пример вопроса:

[Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-python)

На traducir:

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14104

Мог бы сам добавить вариант перевода, но не понятно как перевести "community effort".
"Общественные усилия" из гуглопереводчика, естественно, не вариант.

Comment: У нас такие сообщения называются общими вроде. Там на самом деле 3 строки перевести надо: [раз](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13855), [два](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14104), [три](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14101). Я б предложил "Ответы на этот вопрос являются общими".

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, остальные строки я проверял - этих строк нет на transifex (если перейти по key - ничего не находит).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предложил перевод: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14104

> `**Ответы на этот вопрос были написаны [совместными усилиями сообщества]($CommunityWiki$)**. Для улучшения этого сообщения отредактируйте существующие ответы. Публикация новых ответов и другие действия для него недоступны.`

Comment: По-моему отличный вариант

Comment: Утвердил перевод.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik не очень понятно, в каких случаях появляется эта плашка. Например, почему её нет [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/176217)?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Появляется для вопросов, в которых заблокировано добавление новых ответов (но не заблокировано редактирование). "Книги и материалы..." никак не заблокирован, вероятно, по недосмотру.

Comment: Видимо, это совсем что-то новенькое. Так как я не помню, что можно было блокировать написание новых ответов отдельно от возможности редактирования существующих. И что за статус у этих вопросов? Т.е. можно ли их искать (без SEDE)? Вот `locked:1 wiki:1 is:q answers:1` здесь, получается, не подходит. Может @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik подскажет о наличии какой-то новой модераторской опции на этот счёт.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ это вопрос был заблокирован сто лет назад ещё Ником. А плашки такие недавно ввели.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik я к тому, что как он был заблокирован именно на новые ответы, а не вообще полностью. Вот такого я не помню.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ [сейчас 4 варианта](https://monosnap.com/file/yL3f8TnXoztKsFhrChGeXYSVo7gM4I). 3 вроде всегда были. Последний (на комментарии) добавился недавно.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik Получается "ответ от имени сообщества" как раз, видимо.

Comment: Задал вопрос на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346703/339911).